# How to increase company logo image size on qweb report

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-13

I do not have an idea of how I can increase the company logo on qweb report.
This is the report.
[image]

How do I increase the company logo at the top left hand corner of the picture?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Odoo will call the web [external_layout_standard](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/web/views/report_templates.xml#L340) when the document template is not set in the company (where the header is defined) and the size of the image is limited in height using the [max-height](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/13.0/addons/web/views/report_templates.xml#L276) attribute.

Try to increase the `max-height` defined on the `img` tag using the style attribute.

***Example:***

```xml
<template id="external_layout_custom_img_style" inherit_id="web.external_layout_standard">
    <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('col-3')]/img" position="attributes">
        <attribute name="style">max-height: 64px;</attribute>
    </xpath>
</template>
```